# I want Country of Manufacture in my filter

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes, layered-navigation

[image: New Product Creation]

I want Country of Manufacture in my filter. I am Using Magento 2

Comment: In frontend filters or admin grid filters?

Comment: in frontend Filters

Comment: Can you tell me, Where I can find it?

Comment: Is @lalit's answer working for you? I think this setting is for admin panel.

Comment: For frontend filters, setting is disabled for this attribute. I think you need to write custom module to override this setting or create a custom attribute for country of manufacturer.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora to enable in naviagation filter you must add it to global and all product must have value so i can show as filter in frontend .just follow other attributes..

Comment: @lalitmohan, I can understand what you say, but since **`country_of_manufacture`** is a system attribute and it has been defined for **`website`** and has been set 0 for filterable, I suggested to either override attribute by custom module or create a new attribute for the same.

Comment: its working bro

Comment: @MohitKumarArora I agree with you. Just post your solution..

Comment: @PrakashRaj, can you post what you have done to make it work?

Comment: can you post the solution>?

Answer (score 0):

**Got to : Stores->Attributes->product**
[image]

[image]

Comment: It can't be changed like that.

Answer (score 0):

Since **`country_of_manufacture`** (**Country of Manufacture**) is a system attribute and there are following (non-changeable) settings:

- **Use in Layered Navigation:** No
- **Use in Search Results Layered Navigation:** No
- **Scope:** Website

To make an attribute filterable in the frontend, you should have the following settings:

- **Use in Layered Navigation:** Yes
- **Use in Search Results Layered Navigation:** Yes
- **Scope:** Global

So, in my opinion, you should either create a new custom attribute for the country of manufacture or override the settings of the current attribute by creating a custom module.

Please let me know how did you found it working.